# DBSCAN clustering - what happens when border point of one cluster is considered to be core point of another cluster

Tags: cluster-analysis, dbscan, non-deterministic

I would like to know your opinion about dbscan clustering, I am trying to implement algorithm as published [here](https://www.aaai.org/Papers/KDD/1996/KDD96-037.pdf). In my opinion there is possibility for one point from border of some cluster to be an core point of another one as shown in picture:

[image].

I think there are some of the possible solutions:

- we could consider point as written to cluster and that cannot be changed - but we could lost second cluster because of that
- we could be able to change border points cluster but without recomputing epsilon neighbourhood.
- we could be able to add point into multiple clusters (worst one).

What do you think is the best? Or am I getting something completely wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core-point property is *not cluster specific*.

Either the point is a core point, or it is not; independent of which cluster it is in.

If it is a core point, then it cannot be a noise or border point anymore.

Whenever two core points are neighbors, they by definition are in the same cluster.

The known special case that can happen is that one point is *border* to more than one cluster. See end of page 229.